# Shortcut to a specific folder using the "My Files" file manager

Tags: samsung, file-system, files, home-screen-shortcuts

I have a non-rooted Samsung Galaxy A3 with Android 5. I have an app icon on the desktop for "My Files" app, but how is it possible to create a shortcut for `SD card\books\` on the desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, in fact the app My Files has this option already:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of your file manager allowing you to create shortcut to a folder.

<del>Seems that the default file manager of Samsung(My Files) doesn't provide that feature.</del>

Just go for another file manager such as [MK Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mkexplorer.kormateusz&hl=en). In the options next to a folder name, you can find `create shortcut`. That will do the job.

This shortcut will persist even if you uninstall the file manager that created it.